# How to Count a Stack of Object using OpenCV ( Android )?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this image and want to count how many card on this image , how to count using openCV ? im already try but its always return only one
original image ( from camera )
[image]

after graying + threshold

[image]

my code

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, gray2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            //Imgproc.threshold(gray2, ada, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
            Imgproc.threshold(gray2,thresh,165,255,THRESH_BINARY);
            
            Imgproc.HoughLinesP(thresh, lines, 1.0, Math.PI / 180, 50, 100.0, 10.0);
            double num_lines = lines.cols();

            for(int j =0; j <= lines.rows();j++){
                if(lines.get(j,0) != null){
                    double [] dArr = lines.get(j,0);
                    Point point1 = new Point(dArr[0],dArr[1]);
                    Point point2 = new Point(dArr[2],dArr[3]);
                    Imgproc.line(
                            thresh,
                            point1,
                            point2,
                            new Scalar(0.0, 255.0, 0.0),
                            1
                    );
                }
            }
```

im already trying to morph and canny but the result make image broke

[image]

are possible to count that object because it so thin ? and the real object i want to count is more thinner.

thanks for the help ! ( sorry for bad english )

i want someone can correct my code / give me a good code how to solve that

Comment: I'd recommend mechanically giving those sheets some separation, so you get a better signal. -- then, take a scanline through the image, and plot that. you'll see bumps and dips representing those sheets. -- canny and hough will mislead you and only ruin the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a little.

However...
I think you must extract interest region (Card part) at first, but I don't know how to, because it may strongly depend on some implicit prior condition about target image (where the cards, background color, etc).

So, here, **my try was started from already extracted region image**.
The figure below is screenshot of my try, including 4 images.

[image]

- Top most image is the extracted region image (this is input for my try. cut outed by hand.)
- The 2nd binalized image is result of OpenCV's `adaptiveThreshold`. Obtaining ideal binalization result is often very difficult/unrealistic for real scene. So, this result is also not "ideal", as you see (All cards don't be separated perfectly).
- The 3rd shows result of `connectedComponentsWithStats` to the 2nd. I drew red lines for each labeled region to represent x-location and width. (some very small regions were ignored)

At this point, it seems that width of most regions is a good representation of the width of the card.
So, I estimated card width from this result.
What I did is very simple :

1. Calculate average of width values.
2. Remove width values which very differ from the average.
3. Go back to 1. if at least one value removed. Else, current average value is estimation result.

Then, finally, I re-counted the number of cards.
Just divided region width by estimated card width, for each region.
The 4th image in screenshot is the result. I drew green lines for each estimated card location.
Re-count result becomes to `26`.

I hope this post can be a bit of help to you.